# Tableview row, changing last cell changes the first

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I'm having a lot of trouble with cell constraint modifications. I have a tableview with a nested cell inside of it and a button.

[image: schedule cells]

The bottom `more` button has a constraint to share the bottom of the cell. There is also a view hiding behind it with a height constraint, you can see it peeking out the bottom.

Basically if I click the the two constraints are changed and the cell is expanded.

**TableViewCell:**

```
@IBAction func expandPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    if expandButtonBottomConstraint.active {
        self.expandButtonBottomConstraint.active = false
        self.descriptionTextHeightConstraint.constant =      
    self.descriptionTextHeightConstraint.constant * 10          
    self.tableView.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: buttonIndex, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }        
}
```

**TableViewController**

```
override func tableView(tableview: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let eventCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventTableViewCell") as! EventTableViewCell
...
eventCell.buttonIndex = indexPath.row
....
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If you click on the first event it expands, but if you click on on the third one, the third ***and the first*** expands. The index row is correctly the right row. How can I only expand a particular row consistently?

Comment: Cells can be reused, so you need to keep track of which rows are expanded and which aren't somewhere other than the cell itself.  Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you configure the cell appropriately

Comment: if the only thing changes is the layout, you dont need reload cell, just call `tableView.beginUpdate()` and `endUpdate()`

Comment: just to check, how many sections do you have? and also why did you have 2 tableview twice `self.tableView.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: buttonIndex, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)`